# Android Get Serial Number on Zebra Scanners

Tags: android

In the recent versions of Android google has prevented an app from returning a devices serial number.  I have an internal company app that is installed on company owned android devices.  Is there any way to programmatically get the device serial number?

Comment: Without knowing which model of device, I recommending checking existing SDKs: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners.html for possible solutions. Otherwise reach out to the manufacturer directly as those devices tend to be for industrial/POS purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most problems the answer is found knowing how to google your question. In case anyone else has this problem in the future.  The solution for zebra scanners can be found here.

https://developer.zebra.com/blog/access-serial-number-and-imei-mobile-computers-running-android-10